# NullReferenceException handling Ending event for Video

Tags: c#, directx

I'm making a C# Windows Forms application that plays a video at some point, using DirectX Managed code. I want the app to exit right after playing the video, so I tried to handle the Ending event for the video and it raises and exception.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Picture_Button
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Video video = new Video("C:\\Users\\Pushkin\\Desktop\\PPAP.mp4");
        //Video video = new Video("C:\\Users\\Pushkin\\Desktop\\PPAP.mp4");
        private int clicks = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            video.Ending += new System.EventHandler(this.Video_Ending);
            //video.Ending += Video_Ending;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clicks++;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (clicks)
            {
                case 0: pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Pineapple; break;
                case 1: pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Apple; break;
                case 2: pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Pen; break;
                case 3:
                    {
                        video.Owner = this;
                        video.Play();
                        /*video.Dispose();
                        Application.Exit();*/
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void Video_Ending(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            video.Dispose();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback
  StackTrace:
  at VideoWndProc(HWND__* hWnd, UInt32 uMsg, UInt32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
  InnerException:
```

Also, I've noticed that the program works perfectly without the code for the Ending event.

Comment: If the code is fully managed, do you even need to manually dispose the video?

Comment: I've seen that post, but I can't see what exactly is wrong with my code

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to manually dispose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs because the Video component still tries to do things after the event handler returns. So, you cannot dispose of the component in the handler.

Call the`Close` method of the form in the handler. This will close the form after the handler has returned and after the Video component has finished.

```
private void Video_Ending(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Close();
}
```

Disposing the Video component is optional in this case, because we know that the application terminates after closing the form anyway. (When a process exits, all its resources are freed).

If this form was part of a larger project, it would be a good idea to dispose of the Video component. The correct place for that is the FormClose event of the form.

Comment: Could you please add the code?

Comment: Ok thanks, it works well on my computer, but the release crashes on any other computer, is it related to this or should I make another post for this issue?

Comment: @CosminPetolea One question for each problem. Make sure to post full error information. Just a hint: You need to make sure that .net framework 3.5 is installed on the other computer and you need to distribute the dlls for "Direct X for Managed Code". Also make sure a valid codec for the video format is installed.